# Ruby - Create key value pairs from variable

Tags: ruby

How to create a key value pair from the following data using ruby?

```
result="-e hostname=webserver001 -e username=root -e password=testing123"
```

I want to parse it and produce and produce the following output:

```rb
{"hostname"=>"webserver001", "username"=>"root", "password"=>"testing123"}
```

Comment: you could trim by whitespaces and read out the the required strings and then cut by '=' again.

Comment: Can you reply as answer with example?

Comment: It feels to me like you are trying to parse options, maybe a [`OptionParser`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) might be a more robust solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like :

```
    result = " -e hostname=webserver001 -e username=root -e password=testing123"

hash = Hash.new
res = result.split(' -e ')
res.each { |x|
  if x.split('=').length() > 1
    part = x.split('=')
    hash[part[0]] = part[1] 
  end
}
puts hash
```

Comment: it also produces a `nil` key value pair.. How can I avoid the nil key value  pair?

{nil=>nil, "hostname"=>"webserver001 ", "username"=>"root ", "password"=>"testing123"}

Comment: I edited, just add a condition to test if the "x" variable is well formated

Answer (score 1):

```
result = "-e hostname=webserver001 -e username=root -e password=testing123"
```

Code

```
p result.scan(/\w+=\w+/)
        .map { _1.split("=") }
        .to_h
```

Or

```
p Hash[result.scan(/\w+=\w+/)
        .map { _1.split("=") }]
```

Output

```
{"hostname"=>"webserver001", "username"=>"root", "password"=>"testing123"}
```

Comment: What is the `p` here? How can I store the output in a variable?

Comment: I tried to test this in `https://replit.com/languages/ruby` but I get the following error. 
`undefined local variable or method `_1' for main:Object (NameError) exit status 1`

Comment: Also would it match special characters? What if the value password has something like 'P@ssw0rd!_!@#'

Comment: @john ruby 2.7 introduces such a feature for parameter.